# Mysql row import stops when echountering a special character

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

I am runnign into a similar problem as here the one privided below. But the workaround found there is no option for me.

[Euro symbol breaks mysql insertion process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145584/euro-symbol-breaks-mysql-insertion-process)

I am migrating some data for a friend, I have in no way access to the servers or the mysql shell, and I have to import several databases.

Both servers have phpMyAdmin (source: 3.4.10.1deb1 , destination: 3.5.3) but if I export and import a sql file (the dump is still OK), the row import will stop as soon as a special character is about to be insterted, resulting in broken strings.

I have checked, and all tables are `utf8_general_ci` source and destination, the dump has `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;`

Below are the variables, but other then that the session and global are flipped I see no difference there eighter. Any idea what is wrong, and how (and if) I can fix it with limited privileges?

```
Source:
character set client    utf8    
(Global value)  latin1  
 character set connection   utf8    
(Global value)  latin1  
 character set database latin1  
 character set filesystem   binary  
 character set results  utf8
(Global value)  latin1  
 character set server   latin1  
 character set system   utf8

Destination:
character set client    latin1  
(Sessionvariables)  utf8    
character set connection    latin1  
(Sessionvariables)  utf8    
character set database  latin1  
character set filesystem    binary  
character set results   latin1
(Sessionvariables)  utf8    
character set server    latin1  
character set system    utf8
```

Comment: what about the phpmyadmin<->mysql connection? EVERY stage of the process has to be utf8

Comment: Isn't that the character set client? (If not, where can I find it?)

Comment: If I enter the content of the dump directly in phpMyAdmin -> SQL it does work, so something goes wrong with the file upload Ï think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, there is probably something wrong with the connection, but it's not in my power to change that.

The much simpeler solution is to import a gzipped (or other compressed) file rather then a regular SQL file. The compression alters the special characters so they don't break during the upload. Once on the server, everything is utf-8 again and insertion runs as expected.